# jQuery update multiple divs based on returned array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm being beaten by jQuery/ajax.

I'm trying to update multiple table rows on a page with values calculated in a php script called using jQuery sortable.

I can update one row easily enough. Not sure how to add results from ajax script in to an array and send it back, then sort through and update rows.

**Here's my javascript:**

```
<script>
$(function() {                                                           
    $( "#sort tbody" ).sortable({ 
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('#sort tbody').sortable('serialize'); 
            $("#subtotal").load("ajax_update_line_order.php?"+order); 
        },
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight" 
    }); 
    $( "#sort tbody" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

The html is a simple table. I can give each  a unique id or class (not sure which) e.g. row0, row1, row2 etc, the number corresponding to the position.

**Here's my ajax_update_line_order.php:**

```
<?php
........ 

foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item)
{
   //Update position in mysql DB here (all ok)

   //Calculations here (all ok)

   //Add calculated result and position to an array
   $array[] = $calculation; (the array key will match the position here, so guess I can use this to reference when updating the table rows)

}

print_r($array); //Not sure how to get this array back to read and update the page
exit();
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, return the array by JSON-encoding it rather than `print_r`'ing it. The latter is intended for var dumping, i.e. debugging, not programmatic manipulation.

```
exit(json_encode($array));
```

Then in your JS you need a success callback on the AJAX request, to which will be passed (automatically) the parsed JSON, i.e. what started as your PHP array. We then iterate over that array and, for each item in it, output a row.

```
var tbody = $('#sort tbody')
$("#subtotal").load("ajax_update_line_order.php?"+order).done(function(data) {
    for (var i=0, len = data.length; i<len; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr />');
        /* then append some TDs to the row */
        tbody.append(tr);
    }
});
```

If you're new to `done()`, read up on jQuery deferred objects (of which AJAX requests are one example).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm getting there. Just one question, data.length is returning the number of characters in the array, rather than the number of elements. Not sure how to do that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: That means the response is being interpreted as a string, not parsed into an array. Instead of `load()`, use the base `ajax()` method as this affords much more control. Try: `ajax({url: 'ajax_update_line_order.php?'+order, dataType: 'json'})`